# Initialize Highcharts treemap at specific drilldown level

Tags: highcharts, treemap

**[Using this fiddle as an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-large-dataset/)**

I cannot find a way to default to a certain level and selection: in the linked example, if I wanted to start drilled-down into South-East Asia, how could I do so? (as if I had clicked South-East Asia once it loaded)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            type: 'treemap',
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            animationLimit: 1000,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 3
            }],
            data: points
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood - you would like to trigger a drilldown event on the initial load, am I right? If yes, here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b8j1e0L3/) with the example how to achieve it.

```
  if (Highcharts.isString(drillId)) {
    series.setRootNode(drillId, true, {
      trigger: 'click'
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know how to make it drill down to depth 2? For example, not just South-East Asia, but India or Bangladesh.